# Top part of my touchscreen is not working

Tags: touchscreen

Moto C plus | Android 7 | Rooted

Suddenly top part doesn't work. In the test, if I keep on moving in the white area, evetually, one random one will turn green. Also a few minutes before, it was only one white row. I didn't drop the phone or get water in it when this started.

Any idea what it could be and how I can fix it?

[image: Touch test]

Comment: you can still [control](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) device via adb,
or [resize](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.itdo.screenresizer) the screen,
or try to [repair](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apps.redpi.touchscreenrepair) via app,
or try this [trick](https://youtu.be/VERfODYHX3g) with lighter igniter